# Calling ajax request after page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

How to call ajax request after page redirecting? I'm trying with setInterval function, but it doesn't work.

```
$("#list").on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        var id = data[0];

        var url = 'redirect.html?=id';

        window.location.href = url + id;
        return false;

        var getRequest = setInterval (function(id) {

            $.ajax({url: "/list?id=" + id,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert(status);
                },
                success: function (listsdata) {
                    oTable = $('#table2').DataTable({
                        data: listsdata,
                        columns: [
                            { title: "Column1" },
                            { title: "Column2" },
                        ]
                     });  
                }
            });
        }, 3000);

    });
```

`getRequest()` method cannot be executed

Comment: you're returning false before you ever get to getRequest()

Comment: Everything after `return false;` is not executing. Try to move `setInterval` above this statement

Comment: AFAIK, when the page is redirected, your current code will be unused. The code execution will be terminated. Anyway, besides the `return false` issue, `getRequest` is not a function, it's receiving the `setInterval` id.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). When redirect occurs a new page loads and script from current page doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Thanks guys.. I've passed id through the URL execute function in a new page.